# How to read a textfile containing a comma separated list and store each word that is separated by a comma into a separate array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hello I am trying to figure out how I would read a line in a comma separated text file and store each word that is separated by a comma in the file into a separate array.

For example if the line in the file was

```
Dog, blue, large
```

Then I would like to have 3 different arrays that store one word from the list. So would array 1 would store Dog, array 2 stores blue, and array 3 stores large.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Dog, blue, large";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");
String[] array = new String[st.countTokens()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = st.nextToken().trim();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `String` utils for removing spaces and split the text.

```
String text = "Dog, blue, large";
String[] split = text.trim().split(",");
```

`.trim()` removes the whitespace and `.split(",")` splits the string.